# Set Makefile variable inside target

Tags: makefile

I have a target inside a makefile:

```
all: $(TARGETS)
```

I want a variant that differs from `all` only by the fact that it sets an environment variable. Something like:

```
all-abc: $(TARGETS)
    ABC=123
```

but that doesn't work because the dependencies are processed before the variable is set. I've thought about having another dependency before the real ones that just sets the environment variable but I don't think the environment persists across targets. That is to say that

```
abc:
    ABC=123
all-abc: abc $(TARGETS)
```

doesn't work. What I ultimately want to be able to do is

```
$ make all-abc
```

instead of

```
$ ABC=123 make
```

Is it possible to set an environment variable like this ?

(GNU Make 3.82)

Comment: What's wrong with `make all ABC=123`?

Comment: prefer not to have to worry about the values to set the variables to (i.e. in the example I don't want to have to remember `123`)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

try this:

```
all:
    @#usual rule, if you call `make all-abc`, this will print "123"
    @echo $(ABC)

all-abc: ABC=123
all-abc: all
    @#what you put here it's going to be executed after the rule `all`
```

Comment: yes that's good. I didn't think of adding two targets with the same name. Good one!

Comment: starfry: I don't think you're understanding what this does exactly.  You should read the section of the GNU make manual on target-specific variables.

Comment: To add to what @MadScientist said: there are not two targets with the same name here.  "all-abc: ABC=123" defines a target-specific variable; it is not a target.  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

Comment: I use `xargs` within a target command, and I needed to do `all-abc: export ABC=123` to make the variable accessible from the command executed by xargs