# How to export variables from makefile rule?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have in my `Makefile` rule which setup environment:

```
.ONESHELL:
set_db_env:
    export DB_USER=XXX
    export DB_PASS=YYY
```

May I reuse `set_db_env` target?

```
another_rule: set_db_env
    echo ${DB_USER}
```

I also have found [.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eEXPORT_005fALL_005fVARIABLES) but do not understand how to use it.

**UPD**
I have found this works:

```
$(shell ${APP} db_env > ${CONF_DIR}/db_env.conf)
include ${CONF_DIR}/db_env.conf
```

But I do not think this is good approach

Comment: Does your `set_db_env` rule/recipe actually work?  That should run each `export` statement in a separate shell in which case I would expect errors regarding `:=` being invalid syntax.

Comment: @G.M.:  I have updated question. But in any case it exports to one parent shell, does not?

Comment: Take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229833/set-environment-variable-inside-target). This should brings you some light.

Comment: @perror: Yes, I see it before. It is too verbose to write N `export VAR` lines before each rule. I want to reuse all them with only one command: `set_db_env`

Comment: @EugenKonkov: I did not know `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES`, but this seems to be what you are looking for! [Here is an example of how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900167/export-all-variables-works-only-when-made-phony). Basically, you just have to declare it as an empty target in the Makefile.

Comment: @perror: `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` exports variables to *child processes,* not to *dependent rules.* But I think there's a way...

Answer (score 9):

In general, variables do not pass from one rule to another. But there is a way to do this with [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
another_rule: DB_USER=XXX
another_rule: DB_PASS=YYY                              

another_rule:
    @echo user is ${DB_USER}
    @echo pass is $(DB_PASS)
```

If writing so many extra lines for every rule is too tedious, you can wrap them in a function:

```
define db_env
$(1): DB_USER=XXX
$(1): DB_PASS=YYY
endef

$(eval $(call db_env,another_rule))
another_rule:
    @echo user is ${DB_USER}
    @echo pass is $(DB_PASS)
```

Comment: May you please provide more description about what is going here? I read [call](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html) but still do not understand how `db_env` work where. And why you specify target name as argument to call.

Comment: @EugenKonkov: "another_rule" is the first parameter, so `call` assigns that value to the temporary variable `1`, so when `call` expands the variable `db_env`, each instance of "$(1)" becomes "another_rule".

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution could be to use [pattern specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern_002dspecific-Variable-Values):

My use case:

```
staging%: export DB_HOST="127.0.0.1"
staging%: export DB_NAME="yolo"

staging-shell:
    @echo "My host is ${DB_HOST}"

staging-server:
    @echo "My host is ${DB_HOST}"
```